# Have iTunes inform me when I programmatically sync iphone using COM

Tags: iphone, windows, com, itunes, synchronize

I've [written an application](http://code.google.com/p/tiecal/) that synchronizes calendar from Lotus Notes to the iphone (using MS Outlook as conduit) and I want to tell iTunes to push the changes onto the iphone.

I can do this just fine using the COM interface ([IITIpodSource.UpdateIpod](http://cuzic.net/iTunesLib/classes/IITIPodSource.html)) but the problem is that this method return immediately when it starts the synchronization. Then iTunes will handle the rest. I want my application to be informed when iTunes has completed the sync so that I can update my GUI accordingly.

So, while iTunes is synchronizing the iphone correctly, my application is never told **when** it is done. A status flag that I can poll is just as OK as an event by the way...

I can't find anything of help in the documentation. Has anyone ever tried anything like this?

**Edit:** I tried polling the [FreeSpace](http://cuzic.net/iTunesLib/classes/IITSource.html) property but it seems that is updated before the syncing is done (may even be updated several times as far as I can tell)

Comment: Will EjectIPod lock until its finished syncing?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. It makes itunes pop up a dialog asking the user if he really wants the ipod to be ejected during sync. During this time EjectIpod call is blocked. If I click "no", the sync continues and EjectIpod returns with no error message or return value (it's a void method)

Answer (score 1):

Try to do something else directly on the iPod (e.g. create a new playlist - ejection may be a little "too hard" unless you can reinsert the iPod programmatically). At least through the GUI you can only do that when the synch has completed.

Comment: Good suggestion, but unfortunately it didn't work. I tried both creating a playlist and a folder but I get "source isn't modifiable" exception (even after sync is completed). I guess it has to do with whether you use manual or automatic sync of music on the iphone (i.e. "Manually manage music and videos")

Comment: Hmm .. can you check for the existence of a playlist on the iPod? (Or as the interface to enumerate the existing playlists for you?)

Comment: yes I can query and enumerate them. I can also enumerate the tracks in each playlist while the sync is in progress..